Have trouble running JAX on Metal
I tried intalling JAX for metal on a venv as mentioned on https://developer.apple.com/metal/jax/, and when I try to verify it, I get a really large error.
Here's what I used to install it:
python3 -m venv ~/jax-metal
source ~/jax-metal/bin/activate
python -m pip install -U pip
python -m pip install numpy wheel
python -m pip install jax-metal

And here's what I used to verify it (just printing a small np array with jax):
python -c 'import jax; print(jax.numpy.arange(10))'

And then I get this really huge error that I can't make sense of:
Platform 'METAL' is experimental and not all JAX functionality may be correctly supported!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ridhibandaru/jax-metal/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/xla_bridge.py", line 887, in backends
    backend = _init_backend(platform)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/ridhibandaru/jax-metal/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/xla_bridge.py", line 973, in _init_backend
    backend = registration.factory()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/ridhibandaru/jax-metal/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/xla_bridge.py", line 667, in factory
    xla_client.initialize_pjrt_plugin(plugin_name)
  File "/Users/ridhibandaru/jax-metal/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jaxlib/xla_client.py", line 177, in initialize_pjrt_plugin
    _xla.initialize_pjrt_plugin(plugin_name)
jaxlib.xla_extension.XlaRuntimeError: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Mismatched PJRT plugin PJRT API version (0.47) and framework PJRT API version 0.54).

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/ridhibandaru/jax-metal/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/numpy/lax_numpy.py", line 4264, in arange
    output = _arange(start, stop=stop, step=step, dtype=dtype)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/ridhibandaru/jax-metal/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/numpy/lax_numpy.py", line 4304, in _arange
    return lax.iota(dtype, start)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/ridhibandaru/jax-metal/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/lax/lax.py", line 1338, in iota
    return broadcasted_iota(dtype, (size,), 0)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/ridhibandaru/jax-metal/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/lax/lax.py", line 1348, in broadcasted_iota
    return iota_p.bind(*dynamic_shape, dtype=dtype, shape=tuple(static_shape),
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/ridhibandaru/jax-metal/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/core.py", line 429, in bind
    return self.bind_with_trace(find_top_trace(args), args, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/ridhibandaru/jax-metal/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/core.py", line 433, in bind_with_trace
    out = trace.process_primitive(self, map(trace.full_raise, args), params)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/ridhibandaru/jax-metal/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/core.py", line 939, in process_primitive
    return primitive.impl(*tracers, **params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/ridhibandaru/jax-metal/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jax/_src/dispatch.py", line 87, in apply_primitive
    outs = fun(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: Unable to initialize backend 'METAL': INVALID_ARGUMENT: Mismatched PJRT plugin PJRT API version (0.47) and framework PJRT API version 0.54). (you may need to uninstall the failing plugin package, or set JAX_PLATFORMS=cpu to skip this backend.)
--------------------
For simplicity, JAX has removed its internal frames from the traceback of the following exception. Set JAX_TRACEBACK_FILTERING=off to include these.

Where's this coming from? How do I fix this?
